# Find all positive integers $k≤100$ s.t. $\exists$ an integer $n$ where $3n^6+27n^4+33n^2+1$ is a multiple of $k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all positive integers $k\leq 100$ such that there exists an integer $n$ where $3n^6+27n^4+33n^2+1$ is a multiple of $k$.

I have literally no idea how to begin this question except that I tried to check modular arguments as in $\bmod 3$ we can rule out $33$ numbers, and so on (but I feel it is too bashy and takes up a lot of time). It would be thankful if we can think about the generalization as well as in $P(x) \equiv 0 \bmod a$ as $a \in \mathbb{N}$ and if not then what what about the same question but with $10000$ instead of $100$. Thank you.

Comment: you just have to check for k prime; on the other hand the expression cannot be divisible by 3 as it is in the form 3k+1

Comment: why only for k= prime?

Comment: if you have two numbers a and b, a divides b iff all the prime divisors of a divide b; so once you've found all the primes that divide the expression, the solution will simply be the set of all the possible product combination

Comment: Please give some context, e.g. is any knowledge of advanced (algebraic) number theory assumed known, or is the problem assuming only knowledge of elementary number theory (first course)?

Comment: I'd like to assume for the latter @BillDubuque.

Comment: I have updated the tags. Is the source of the problem a textbook on elementary number theory, or some programming contest?

Comment: "so once you've found all the primes that divide the expression, the solution will simply be the set of all the possible product combination"  How so? If there is is a term that is a multiple of $p$ and another that is a multiple of $q$ how would it follow there is a term that is a multiple of $pq$ or of $p^k$ or $p^kq^m$?

Comment: @fleablood This follows from the Chinese remainder theorem. Let $n_1$ be a root $\mod p$ and $n_2$ a root $\mod q$. Then by crt we find a number $n$ that satisfies $n \equiv n_1 \pmod p$ and $n \equiv n_2 \pmod q$, so $f(n) \equiv f(n_1) \equiv 0 \pmod p$ and $f(n) \equiv f(n_2) \equiv 0 \pmod q$ hence $n$ is a root of $f$ mod $pq$. Only thing used here is that $p$ and $q$ are coprime and that $f$ is a polynomial.

Comment: @ploosu2  I need coffee.

Comment: @temp Wouldn't that mean that you have to check for $k$ a prime *power*?

Comment: @ploosu2 You'd need to check all prime *powers* up to $100$. Of course you get $2^6=f(1)$ for free and $3$ is impossible, so that just leaves $5^2$ and $7^2$. Of course neither work because you can only get prime divisors $p\equiv1\pmod{18}$. Another obvious value to check is $f(3)$, yielding $p=73$ and so you are left to check $p=19$ and $p=37$.

Comment: @fleablood yeah you're right my bad, I gave it too little thought

Comment: Thanks for the little hints, let me try it again!